# Ability to request Pins by tags from Pinterest API

Tags: search, request, pinterest

I want to request Pins without login to Pinterest by providing a set of tags. Is this possible? I searched through current Pinterest API and couldn't find anything like some search method. I know that I can get a google custom search engine and fetch photos from pinterest.com source from google but wanted to do it natively.

Any help appreciated!